# Iterating a Numpy Array for random.normal generator shape conflict

Tags: python, numpy, pymc3

I am trying to generate n (in this case n=57) random numbers from a normal distribution for a number of sampled mean and standard deviations from a PyMc3 model (in this case 350).  So I ultimately want to end up with 350 distributions of 57 length each.  I'm sure this is something straightforward and I have a lack of conceptual understanding.  Input is:

```
 prior_pc5 =pm.sample_prior_predictive(samples=350,model=model_5,
    var_names='μ','σ'],random_seed=21)

    n=57

    prpc5_μ = np.asarray(prior_pc5['μ'])
    prpc5_σ = np.asarray(prior_pc5['σ'])

for x,y in np.nditer([prpc5_μ,prpc5_σ]):
    y_prpc5 = np.random.normal(prpc5[:,0],prpc5[:,1], size=n)
```

Output is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-180-90195f458d14> in <module>
      1 for x,y in np.nditer([prpc5_μ,prpc5_σ]):
----> 2     y_prpc5 = np.random.normal(prpc5[:,0],prpc5[:,1], size=n)

mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.normal()

_common.pyx in numpy.random._common.cont()

_common.pyx in numpy.random._common.cont_broadcast_2()

__init__.pxd in numpy.PyArray_MultiIterNew3()

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Appreciate any edification you can provide.

Comment: Why are you using `nditer`?

Comment: the interwebs encouraged nditer to iterate through an array.  prpc5 is defined in the complete code, but I omitted it for brevity.  In any case, when I turn the prpc5 dict into individual arrays I have two 1D arrays of length 350.

Answer (score 0):

Your `nditer` loop does nothing for you.  You don't even use the `x,y` variables. The `prpc5` variable is undefined. And there's no attempt to accumulate the `y_prpc5` values.

If you need to iterate on something, start with a plain iteration.  Don't attempt to use `nditer` (unless you can read and understand all of its docs).  It's not any faster, and harder to use correctly.

But the error has nothing to do with `nditer`.

```
np.random.normal(prpc5[:,0],prpc5[:,1], size=n)
```

doesn't use any iteration variables.

Size with scalar arguments:

```
In [63]: np.random.normal(1,2,size=57)                                                         
Out[63]: 
array([-0.15095176,  0.68354153,  0.64270214,  1.71539129,  3.82930345,
       -0.93888021,  0.34013012,  4.7390541 ,  1.95647694, -0.02787572,
        0.53790931,  3.64859278, -2.66455301, -1.81567149,  2.62141742,
       -0.22887411, -0.36284743,  2.92298403,  1.87943503,  2.12060767,
       -1.10172555,  0.04234386,  0.48707306,  5.66358341,  0.70659526,
       -0.74210809, -2.04678512, -0.16496427, -0.46041457,  0.50505178,
        1.66497518,  2.20486689,  1.83034991, -1.73740446, -3.117619  ,
        1.12649528,  2.58059286,  1.42897399,  2.37256695, -2.34670202,
        3.00318398,  2.78164509, -1.1329154 ,  4.06859674,  3.13266299,
       -0.35481326,  1.79429889,  1.71617491,  1.41543611,  0.9476942 ,
       -0.79856396, -0.83121952, -2.63145461,  0.13941223,  0.18895024,
        3.21956521, -2.75348353])
```

Array/list arguments with size:

```
In [64]: np.random.normal([1,2],[1,1],size=57)                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-9a493d59b8d2> in <module>
----> 1 np.random.normal([1,2],[1,1],size=57)

mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.normal()

_common.pyx in numpy.random._common.cont()

_common.pyx in numpy.random._common.cont_broadcast_2()

__init__.pxd in numpy.PyArray_MultiIterNew3()

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

If size matches the size of the first two arguments, ok:

```
In [65]: np.random.normal([1,2],[1,1],size=2)                                                  
Out[65]: array([1.91404732, 2.79305575])
```

Comment: To clarify I would like to generate 350 samples from a normal distribution with each sample 57 in length.  How would I do this with np.random.normal?